# Can I transfer Windows 7 to a different hard drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd

As well as upgrading my graphics card I'm looking to get an SSD to add to my current 1TB Hard drive.

I would ideally like windows to run from the SSD and I'd like to format the hard drive as it's full of years of junk and I want to start fresh. What would be the simplest way of just transferring all needed windows files that would then allow my computer to function as a fresh install if I formatted the original hard drive?

I still have the install disk for Windows 7 but it's an OEM licence so, from what I've read, I can't just do a fresh install (EDIT) as the licence is non-transferable? Or does it being on the same processor etc. mean it will install with the same licence key?

If I'm thinking about this the completely wrong way then please let me know

Comment: You should be able to install it, even if it is a OEM license. I would go with a clean install instead of trying to hack some solution. I only remember XP not accepting license keys from OEM from non OEM cd's, since Vista you can use any install media (I think).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What would be the simplest way of just transferring all needed windows files that would then allow my computer to function as a fresh install if I formatted the original hard drive?

Do a fresh install from CD/DVD

> I still have the install disk for Windows 7 but it's an OEM licence so, from what I've read, I can't just do a fresh install.

An OEM install disk will *only* do a fresh install.

Comment: You can always use the key on the sticker on your OEM system to do this.

Comment: Oh, I just read that OEM licences are non-transferable but I guess as I've got the same processor etc. the checks it uses would come back okay?

Comment: Correct, they are not transferrable. But upgrading parts in a machine is not transferring a license to a different machine.

Answer (score 0):

> I still have the install disk for Windows 7 but it's an OEM licence so, from what I've read, I can't just do a fresh install (EDIT) as the licence is non-transferable?

The license is not transferable to a new computer but replacing your hard drive with a SSD does not count as a new computer. IIRC the official Microsoft line is that replacing the motherboard for reasons other than repair counts as a "new computer". Any other upgrade is considered to be still the same computer.

If it's a "Direct OEM" copy (license sticker and media branded with the name of the PC manufacturer) the install disk should be keyed to the motherboard BIOS and should activate automatically. If it's a "system builder" copy (license sticker and media not branded with the name of the PC manufacturer) then you will have to use the key on the sticker to activate online or by phone.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm presuming that as I built this PC from separate components I probably have a "system builder" copy (Not at home at the moment so I can't check)